# svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 URL_Reputation_coaching) in response to GET request

Tags: svn, gcc

When I do svn checkout for GCC I get the below error. SVN Version is 1.6.11 (r934486)

"svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 URL_Reputation_coaching) in   response to GET request for '/svn/gcc/!svn/ver/219188/trunk/libitm/configure.ac"

Command:

> svn checkout http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk /home/softwares/GCC

Google shows results for (403 FORBIDDEN) errors but none for (403 URL_Reputation_coaching)

Please help out.

Note: I can do an ls and list the branches

> svn ls http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc

Comment: I didn't have any problem with: `svn checkout svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk` using svn 1.8.8 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I see. I am on RHEL and svn 1.6. Do you know anything about the error "403 URL_Reputation_coaching"

Comment: No, but [HTTP error 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) means **forbidden**, maybe this is given because you use "http". I was actually NOT able to download the svn with `http://`, but only with `svn://`, did you try this?

Comment: Ok. svn protocol didn't work for me (I am behind a corporate proxy)  so tried http. I have set the http proxy correctly in /home/.subversion/servers.

Comment: Did you also try the `https://` protocol? That one seemed to work for me, but it was quite slow.

Comment: Seems to be working! Thanks. I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [gcc web](https://gcc.gnu.org/svn.html):

> Assuming you have version 1.0.0 and higher of Subversion installed, you can check out the GCC sources using the following command:
>
> ```
> svn checkout svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk SomeLocalDir
> ```

But behind a firewall:

> If you are behind a firewall that does not allow the svn protocol through, you can replace svn:// with http://.

Trying however, I found out that instead of `http://` you should use `https://`:

```
svn checkout https://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/ SomeLocalDir
```

The error 403 could indeed refer to the [HTTP error 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) which means forbidden, and therefore might explain why you were not able to access the SVN through http.